# mongo how to use $in for multiple fields

Tags: mongodb

I am pretty new to Mongo.

```
#1#
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(3990025630833),
    "TicId" : 1012849,
    "OrgId" : 929   
    "Nms" : {
        "Cmp" : "YourCorp AR",
        "Org" : "YourCorp",
        "Wkg" : "NGA_T1",
        "Srv" : "Performance management"
    },
}

#2#
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(3990025630833),
    "TicId" : 1012859,
    "OrgId" : 929   
    "Nms" : {
        "Cmp" : "YourCorp AR",
        "Org" : "YourCorp",
        "Wkg" : "NGA_T2_Compensation",
        "Srv" : "Hire management"
    },
}

#3#
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(3990025630833),
    "TicId" : 1012869,
    "OrgId" : 929   
    "Nms" : {
        "Cmp" : "YourCorp BE",
        "Org" : "YourCorp",
        "Wkg" : "NGA_T1",
        "Srv" : "Finance"
    },
}
```

There are 2 fields `Nms.Cmp` and `Nms.Wkg` that I'm querying on.
`Cmp` is company. `Wkg` is workgroup. A company can contain several workgroups.
A user can or cannot be a manager of a company.
When a user is manager of a company we don't look further for workgroups. When user is a simple agent of company, then we need to look for the workgroups he has access to.
So for example:

```
$or:[
    {$and:[
        {'Nms.Cmp':{$eq:'YourCorp AR'}},
        {'Nms.Wkg':{$in:[
            'NGA_T2_Compensation',
            'NGA_T2_Gatekeeper',
            'NGA_T2_WorkforceAdmin']}}]},
    {$and:[
        {'Nms.Cmp':{$eq:'YourCorp BE'}}]},
    {$and:[
        {'Nms.Cmp':{$eq:'YourCorp CO'}}]}]
```

User is manager of 'YourCorp BE', so no need to look in the list of workgroups. But user is only an agent of 'YourCorp AR' and has access to following workgroups :

```
'NGA_T2_Compensation','NGA_T2_Gatekeeper','NGA_T2_WorkforceAdmin'
```

So the query excerpt above will return as result **item #2 and item #3**.
**Item #1 will not** be returned.

Is there a way we can optimize this query so that it makes more use of indexes? `$in` seems to do the trick at least partially but can we use multiple fields in `$in` the same way we do for SQL for eg :

```
select * from tickets 
where (Cmp,Wkg) IN (('YourCorp AR','NGA_T2_Compensation'), ('YourCorp AR','NGA_T2_Gatekeeper'), ('YourCorp AR','NGA_T2_WorkforceAdmin'))
OR (Cmp) IN ('YourCorp BE','YourCorp CO')
```

Thank you

Comment: Just because it's JSON doesn't mean you don't ever have to indent it. So that people can read it.

Comment: @Nicolas In what sense you want to use `$in`? can you provide some sample data and expected output please?

Comment: Hi sorry for the indent.
I added some more details.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, 
has anyone got any ideas?